# How to use SQLite Database to display as a list view in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

So basically my goal is to create a notes a page for people to write text/upload files and display those in a list. Right now I am working on doing it through text. I have never used a Database before and as of right now the code will let the user type in text and it will display it on the screen and add it to the database.

My code:

```
Main Activity: 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Declare references

    EditText userInput;
    TextView recordsTextView;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_Input);
        recordsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.records_TextView);
        /* Can pass nulls because of the constants in the helper.
         * the 1 means version 1 so don't run update.
         */
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        printDatabase();
    }

    //Print the database
    public void printDatabase(){
        String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
        recordsTextView.setText(dbString);
        userInput.setText("");
    }

    //add your elements onclick methods.
    //Add a product to the database
    public void addButtonClicked(View view){
        // dbHandler.add needs an object parameter.
        Products product = new Products(userInput.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addProduct(product);
        printDatabase();
    }

    //Delete items
    public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
        // dbHandler delete needs string to find in the db
        String inputText = userInput.getText().toString();
        dbHandler.deleteProduct(inputText);
        printDatabase();
    }

}
```

MyDBHandler:

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;

        public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
            private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
            public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
            public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
            public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

            //We need to pass database information along to superclass
            public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
                        ");";
                db.execSQL(query);
            }
            //Lesson 51
            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
                onCreate(db);
            }

            //Add a new row to the database
            public void addProduct(Products product){
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
                SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
                db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
                db.close();
            }

            //Delete a product from the database
            public void deleteProduct(String productName){
                SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";");
            }

            // this is goint in record_TextView in the Main activity.
            public String databaseToString(){
                String dbString = "";
                SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
                String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";// why not leave out the WHERE  clause?

                //Cursor points to a location in your results
                Cursor recordSet = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //Move to the first row in your results
        recordSet.moveToFirst();

        //Position after the last row means the end of the results
        while (!recordSet.isAfterLast()) {
            // null could happen if we used our empty constructor
            if (recordSet.getString(recordSet.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
                dbString += recordSet.getString(recordSet.getColumnIndex("productname"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
            recordSet.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }

}
```

Products:

```
public class Products {
    private int _id;
    private String _productname;

    //Added this empty constructor in lesson 50 in case we ever want to create the object and assign it later.
    public Products(){

    }
    public Products(String productName) {
        this._productname = productName;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String get_productname() {
        return _productname;
    }

    public void set_productname(String _productname) {
        this._productname = _productname;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/user_Input"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:width="300dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/add_Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_Input"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/user_Input"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:onClick="addButtonClicked"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/user_Input" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/delete_Button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/add_Button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/user_Input"
        android:onClick="deleteButtonClicked"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/user_Input" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/records_TextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think this link can help you. Basically you add an adapter for ListView, and proceed to read data from a cursor retrieved by querying the database and display it for each row.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter

Comment: try using this [link](https://realm.io/blog/realm-for-android/) its very easy to use and learn

Comment: I wrote a tutorial on this here. Hope it helps. http://codestart.info/android-sqlite-tutorial-with-recyclerview-crud/

Comment: Are you facing any issue? You have mentioned what you want to do and I can also see the relevant code. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use room, it will be easy to use local SQLite db using room, all you need to define entity, dao and database using Room annotations.

For displaying list of records in listview, just create list view adapter and bind record data to views in item layout. I suggest you use RecyclerView instead of listview to get performance benefits.

You can find room and recycler view examples here http://www.zoftino.com/android

Comment: Room and Realm are the same? Because you have mentioned a reference link for Realm.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ListView somewhere (I created a new layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.pelozo.testjava.MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_products"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Create row_product.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Add this method to your database clase:

```
public ArrayList<Products> getProducts(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    ArrayList<Products> products = new ArrayList<Products>();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        Products product = new Products();
        product.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
        product.set_productname(cursor.getString(1));
        products.add(product);
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return products;
}
```

create a ProductsAdapter:

```
public class ProductsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Products> {
// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView id;
    TextView name;
}

public ProductsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Products> products) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_product, products);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Products product = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
    if (convertView == null) {
        // If there's no view to re-use, inflate a brand new view for row
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_product, parent, false);
        viewHolder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_id);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_name);
        // Cache the viewHolder object inside the fresh view
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // View is being recycled, retrieve the viewHolder object from tag
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Populate the data from the data object via the viewHolder object
    // into the template view.
    viewHolder.id.setText("id:" + product.get_id());
    viewHolder.name.setText("name: " + product.get_productname());
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Now just put it all together:

```
    //get db
    MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    //add a product
    dbHandler.addProduct(new Products("Product Name"));
    //retrieve products from db
    ArrayList<Products> productsList = dbHandler.getProducts();
    // Create the adapter
    ProductsAdapter adapter = new ProductsAdapter(this, productsList);
    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_products);
    //set adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```